# adding more than one reviewer to a gitlab merge request

Tags: gitlab, merge-request

I would like to add more than one [reviewer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RZSq6.png) to a merge request.

I tried to add a reviewer, but in gitlab you can only add one. Is there a way to add multiple reviewers to a merge reuest?

Answer (score 0):

To assign multiple reviewers to a merge request follow [these](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/merge_requests/reviews/#from-multiple-users) steps:

> 1. On the left sidebar, select **Search or go to** and find your project.
> 2. Select **Code > Merge requests** and find your merge request.
> 3. On the right sidebar, in the **Reviewers** section, select **Edit**.
> 4. From the dropdown list, select all the users you want to assign to the merge request.
>
> To remove a reviewer, clear the user from the same dropdown list.

Note that **assigning multiple reviewers** is only available for:

> **Tier:** Premium, Ultimate
>
> **Offering:** GitLab.com, Self-managed, GitLab Dedicated